# How to save a customized (only the lower triangle retained) ggpairs graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally, ggpairs

I used the `gpairs_lower` function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656454/5230386) to show only the lower triangle of a `ggpairs` matrix of plots.  But now I have no idea how to save the resulting plot.

The usual method to save a `ggpairs` plot does *not* work here:

```
gpairs_lower <- function(g){
  g$plots <- g$plots[-(1:g$nrow)]
  g$yAxisLabels <- g$yAxisLabels[-1]
  g$nrow <- g$nrow -1

  g$plots <- g$plots[-(seq(g$ncol, length(g$plots), by = g$ncol))]
  g$xAxisLabels <- g$xAxisLabels[-g$ncol]
  g$ncol <- g$ncol - 1

  g
}

library("GGally")
g <- ggpairs(iris[, 1:4], 
             lower  = list(continuous = "points"),
             upper  = list(continuous = "blank"),
             diag  = list(continuous = "blankDiag")
     )


png("graph.png", height = 720, width = 720)
gr <- gpairs_lower(g)
print(gr)
dev.off()

## graph.png is not saved
```

It doesn't work, I believe, because `gpairs_lower` as opposed to `ggpairs` does *not* return a `ggmatrix` object.

[Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055765/richard-telford) Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:  Now the code above works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the default unit of height and width is pixels, so you are saving a 7x7 pixel image!! Try other values or change `units`:

```
png("myPlotMatrix.png", height = 700, width = 700)
g <- ggpairs(iris[, 1:4], 
             lower  = list(continuous = "points"),
             upper  = list(continuous = "blank"),
             diag  = list(continuous = "blankDiag")
)

g<-gpairs_lower(g)
print(g)
dev.off()
```

Look at `?png`:

> width: the width of the device.
>
> height: the height of the device.
>
> units: The units in which height and width are given. Can be px
>   (pixels, the default), in (inches), cm or mm.