# R correlation analysis: ggcorrplot and ggpairs for one group of variables -vs- another group (not all against all)

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, ggpairs, ggcorrplot

I want to do a simple correlation analysis with `ggcorplot` and `ggpairs`. However, I want to compare a group of continuous variables to another group only, not all against all. Let me explain what I mean below.

I am using the `mtcars` data for this example. I do the following:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars
summary(mtcars)
mtcars$vs <- as.character(mtcars$vs)

grDevices::pdf(file="test1.pdf", height=6, width=6)
print(
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(round(cor(mtcars[,1:7]), 1), p.mat = ggcorrplot::cor_pmat(mtcars[,1:7]),
                       hc.order=TRUE, type='lower', method = "circle")
)
grDevices::dev.off()

grDevices::pdf(file="test2.pdf", height=10, width=10)
print(
GGally::ggpairs(mtcars, columns=1:7, ggplot2::aes(colour=vs), legend = 1,
               lower = list(continuous = GGally::wrap("smooth", alpha = 0.5, size=2)),
               upper = list(continuous = GGally::wrap("cor", size=3.5))) +
  ggplot2::theme_light() + ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom")
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

Which produces the following plots:

[image: test1]

[image: test2]

However, I do not want all variables against all, what I would really like here would be to compare variables `mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp` (on the x axis) versus variables `drat`, `wt`, `qsec` (on the y axis).

Ideally, we would not be cropping the plot, but rather doing only the appropriate calculations to save time. In fact, imagine my starting data is separated in 2 input data frames with the different continuous variables (but the same rownames and categorical variables, in this case using `vs`), so more like this:

```
mydata1 <- mtcars[,c(8,1:4)]
mydata2 <- mtcars[,c(8,5:7)]

> head(mydata1)
                  vs  mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4          0 21.0   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag      0 21.0   6  160 110
Datsun 710         1 22.8   4  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive     1 21.4   6  258 110
Hornet Sportabout  0 18.7   8  360 175
Valiant            1 18.1   6  225 105
> head(mydata2)
                  vs drat    wt  qsec
Mazda RX4          0 3.90 2.620 16.46
Mazda RX4 Wag      0 3.90 2.875 17.02
Datsun 710         1 3.85 2.320 18.61
Hornet 4 Drive     1 3.08 3.215 19.44
Hornet Sportabout  0 3.15 3.440 17.02
Valiant            1 2.76 3.460 20.22
```

Any idea how to approach this? Not sure `ggcorrplot` and `ggpairs` are the best for this, but I would stick with them if possible just cause I am more familiar, or at least something that produces a similar `ggplot2`-like output. Thanks!

Comment: Not the fastest solution, but you can control which ggpair panels are shown - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654928/how-to-show-only-the-lower-triangle-in-ggpairs

Comment: Just became aware of the `ggduo` function, also part of `GGally`